# Failed to transform received changeset: Schema mismatch: Property in class is nullable on one side and not on the other

Tags: java, mongodb, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

I am trying to set up an android app with realm, but I get this error: Failed to transform received changeset: Schema mismatch: Property 'firstName' in class 'Customer' is nullable on one side and not on the other.
Both in the android app and in the realm app it is a string.

```
{
  "title": "Customer",
  "properties": {
    "_id": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    },
    "_partition": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "email": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "firstName": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "phone": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

```
public class Customer extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private ObjectId _id = new ObjectId();

    private String _partition;
    @Required
    private String firstName;
    @Required
    private String lastName;

    private String phone;
    @Required
    private String email;
   
    //getters, setters, ctor..
}
```

I can't see what I did wrong, please help.

Comment: At first glance, perhaps you changed the model? e.g. what's on the server, maybe an optional var, does not match your current model, where that var is not optional?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If this is the case shouldn't I get the error "property in class is required on one side and not on the other",I got this before for another property when I removed the required attribute on the client side. Anyway, how can I make it required on the server side, to try what you suggest?

Comment: I would check out the [Optionality](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/android/fundamentals/object-models-and-schemas/#optionality) section of the docs. Perhaps the model had an optional var which was changed to required? Just a guess.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will look into it.