# Realm sync - can't sync because property is not matched on client and server side

Tags: android, synchronization, realm, realm-mobile-platform, object-model

I am trying to use realm sync, I followed the steps in the docs, I created a schema and then copied the java object models that realm suggested in the android app, but for some properties like int, double it gives an error.

The schema:

```
{
  "title": "Invoice",
  "properties": {
    "_id": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    },
    "ownerId": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "customerId": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "date": {
      "bsonType": "date"
    },
    "invoiceItems": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "object",
        "properties": {
          "_id": {
            "bsonType": "objectId"
          },
          "quantity": {
            "bsonType": "int"
          },
          "trackId": {
            "bsonType": "string"
          },
          "unitPrice": {
            "bsonType": "double"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "total": {
      "bsonType": "double"
    }
  }
}
```

The suggested model:
[image]

CASE 1: If I use int and double

```
public class Invoice extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private ObjectId _id;

    private String ownerId;  

    private String customerId;

    private Date date;

    private double total;

    RealmList<InvoiceItem> invoiceItems;

    //getters, setters
}
```

The Error: `Failed to transform received changeset: Schema mismatch: Property 'total' in class 'Invoice' is nullable on one side and not on the other.`

CASE 2: If I use Integer and Double

```
public class Invoice extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private ObjectId _id;

    private String ownerId;  

    private String customerId;

    private Date date;

    private Double total;

    RealmList<InvoiceItem> invoiceItems;

    //getters, setters
}
```

The error: `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: realm.example.mediastore, PID: 12939 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following changes cannot be made in additive-only schema mode: - Property 'Invoice.total' has been made optional. at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm(Native Method) at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.<init>(OsSharedRealm.java:175) at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.getInstance(OsSharedRealm.java:251) at io.realm.BaseRealm.<init>(BaseRealm.java:141) at io.realm.BaseRealm.<init>(BaseRealm.java:108) at io.realm.Realm.<init>(Realm.java:159) at io.realm.Realm.createInstance(Realm.java:495) at io.realm.RealmCache.createInstance(RealmCache.java:494) at io.realm.RealmCache.doCreateRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:461) at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:422) at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:424) ...`

So neither is working. I don't how how to solve this.

Comment: The error is pretty clear **The following changes cannot be made in additive-only schema mode: - Property 'Invoice.total' has been made optional.* - what that means is because you're sync'ing, only additive changes are allowed. If you are changing a property from non-optional to optional (as shown in the error) that's a destructive change and requires wiping the client and re-syncing with the server. This is also very similar to your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69455664/failed-to-transform-received-changeset-schema-mismatch-property-in-class-is-nu)

Comment: In my previous question I wasn't using the object model that realm generated, but tried to build it on my own, and the required attribute was the problem. While here I copied the exact model and still got error. But thanks, I will wipe the client.

Answer (score 1):

Terminating sync, wiping the client and then re-enabling sync solved it.